# Direct limit of a direct system looking like a cochain complex of objects.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, limits-colimits

I would like to ask you about a special kind of direct systems $ (A_i, f_{i}^{j} )_{ i,j \in ( I , \leq ) } $ looking like a cochaîn complex $ (A_i , f_{i}^{j} )_{ i,j \in ( \mathbb{N}^* , \leq ) } $ such that : $ f_{i+1}^{i+2} \circ f_{i}^{i+1} = 0_{A_{i}} $ for all $ i \in \mathbb{N}^* $.

How do we obtain generally and explicitly his direct limit : $ A = \displaystyle \lim_{ \to } A_i $ ? Can you give me an example showing me that ?

I would like to ask you the same question but, replacing a direct limit by an inverse limite, and a cochain complex by a chain of complex.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't you just get $A = 0$?

Comment: Thank you, but how to prove that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The direct limit is always $0$.  More generally, suppose you have a direct system $(A_i, f^j_i)$ such that for each $i$ there is some $j\geq i$ such that $f^j_i=0$ (in your case, you can take $j=i+2$).  Then $\varinjlim A_i=0$.  Indeed, given any object $B$, a map from the direct system to $B$ consists of maps $g_i:A_i\to B$ for each $i$ such that $g_i=g_jf^j_i$ whenever $i\leq j$.  Choosing $j$ such that $f^j_i=0$, you get that $g_i=0$ for all $i$.  It follows that every map from the direct system to any object factors uniquely through the $0$ object, so $0$ is the direct limit.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. :-)  $ A $ looks like : $ \Big( \coprod A_i / \Big) \sim $ up to isomorphism, no ? What is the significance of : $ \Big( \coprod A_i \Big) / \sim \ = 0 $ in this case ?

Comment: The point is that the equivalence relation kills everything.  The equivalence relation says that if $x\in A_i$, then $x\sim f^j_i(x)$ for any $j\geq i$.  But choosing $j$ such that $f^j_i=0$, this says $x\sim 0$.

Comment: Does it mean that : $ A = \coprod A_i $ since there is only one equivalence class $ A = \{ \overline{0} \}  = \Big( \coprod A_i \Big) / \sim $, so : $ A = \coprod A_i $, no ?

Comment: No?  How would that mean $A=\coprod A_i$?

Comment: $ A = \{ ( i , x_i ) \ | \ i \in \mathbb{N} \ \wedge \ x_i \in A_i \ \} = ( A_i )_{ i \in \mathbb{N} } $, no ?

Comment: $ A = \coprod A_i $ means $ A = \coprod A_i $ with $ A_i \to \coprod A_i $ defined by $ x_i \to ( i , x_i ) = ( 0 , \dots , 0 , x_i , 0 , \dots , 0 , \dots \ $

Comment: Since you mod out the equivalence relation which makes everything become $0$, $A$ has only one element, while $\coprod A_i$ has many elements.  They are certainly not the same thing.

Comment: What's about inverse system and his corresponding chain complex ?  :)

Comment: The categorical argument works exactly the same to show that the inverse limit is $0$.